# How to style radcombobox item so that words that wrap are separated

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a RadComboBox and i am being requested to make it look in the following format

```
All
-----------
Cars
-----------
Airplanes
-----------
Airplaned and
Cars
-----------
```

Notice the dashes, those are separating, so in case any of them wrap it look correctly using two rows.

RadComboBox has this property than can be overriden in the css

```
.rcbItem
```

But i have no idea how to achieve this..

I would apprecite any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to add a dashed border to each item?  If so, try adding the following in your CSS.

```
.rcbItem {border-bottom:1px dashed #000;}
```

Replace `#000` with the hex code for your desired border color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.item {
    border-bottom:1px dashed #000;
    color:2B91AF;
    font-size:12px;
    display:block;
}
```